# Query AD for users with create users access rights

Tags: active-directory, permissions, powershell, user-permissions

My company has requested a list with all the users and groups from AD that have access rights to create users and in which OU's they have these rights.

Is there a way to get a complete list via PowerShell for example ? Or any other way ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this with PowerShell (it's probably the easiest way to do it). If you want to understand more about how to do it I'd suggest reading [this Technet 'Hey scripting guy' blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/03/12/use-powershell-to-explore-active-directory-security/), which covers it in pretty good detail.

If you're looking for a ready rolled solution, you can check out [this script](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2013/03/25/active-directory-ou-permissions-report-free-powershell-script-download/). It will probably do what you need with a little customization.

Also I found these with very little Googling effort, there's a wealth of information out there if you look for it.